# Emulator shows some black blurred spot on running android app

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image: My Emulator Image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Try creating a new emulator, and see if it helps. Looks like all the 9-patch pngs are not being rendered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what was wrong...
It was a pretty silly mistake on my part.

1)restart eclipse

2)clean and build the project did  the work..

Thanks for your time Guys...

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of information to go on, but my guess would be that it is due to scaling based on the emulator's resolution and ppi.

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for information on how to support multiple resolutions and densities.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is typical of screwed-up 9-patch files. When those aren't properly formatted (with the appropriate black pixels on North/South & East/West sides) we see that sort of pattern when Android stretches them.

Comment: I dont know the exact reason for them but it wasn't logical. The restart of emulator and eclipse did the trick for me..Anyways thanks for the response